# Tokenize2 check user permission before deleting tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, tokenize2

I'm using Tokenize2 library and need to check if user has permission to delete specific tag or not. Below is my code for this:

```
$('.tokenize').tokenize2({
    dataSource: tagsurl,
    placeholder: 'Add tags for images images.',
    searchMinLength: 3
});
$('.tokenize').on("tokenize:tokens:remove", function(e, value) {
    var checkPermission = checkpermission(userpermissiontagurl, value);
    if (checkPermission) {
    tokensetup(removetagurl, value);
}
return 0;
});
```

The issue is it still hide that tag. How can I make it stop to not hide tag if user can't delete it. Thanks!

[Tokenize2 Events](https://zellerda.github.io/Tokenize2/events.html)

Comment: Umair, There is no direct way to do your requirement. I can suggest two things. 1.Extend Tokenize2 library and override remove method. 2.Post a issue in Tokenize2 git hub page and mark it as feature, So contributor can respond on it.

Comment: @swarooppallapothu I'll try to extend the method. Thanks!